# Access thread variable that changes from main thread

Tags: java, multithreading

So, I am new to threads, and I'm still learning how everything works. So, I couldn't find an answer that would provide an explanation for my problem (to my level of understanding).

I have a `Runnable` class that looks like so:

```
public class Request implements Runnable {
    private Boolean ok = true;

    public synchronized void setOk(Boolean ok) {
        this.ok = ok;
    }

    public synchronized Boolean getOk() {
        return ok;
    }

    private synchronized void foo() {
        //if something happens
        setOk(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true)
            foo();
    }
}
```

And then I have another class that does the following:

```
private static Request request;

private static void spawnThreads() {
    ExecutorService e = new Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    request = new Request();

    e.execute(request); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    spawnThreads();

    while (true) {
        System.out.println(request.getOk());
        if (!request.getOk())
            request.setOk(true);

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    }
}
```

I need that if in the main thread, that `getOk()` returns `false`, do something and set it to `true`. Viceversa, set it to `false` in the thread (which I need to keep on going, no matter what the value of `ok` is at any given time).

As this code is, I can't get the value of `request.getOk()` in the main thread. If I remove the `synchronized` words from the getter and setter, I can access the value in the main thread until a point in time when it is changed by the thread, and never again.

Also, the executor is used because I would create multiple `Request` objects, and waiting for it to shutdown before accessing the variable would contradict my reason for doing this, as I would need all the threads to keep running.

That thread is making http requests to a server (that randomly times out, denies response, etc) and is used to retrieve some information. The `ok` variable is there to take a note when the thread acquires an ok response and some information from the server.

How do I solve it so that the thread can update that variable, but the main thread to be able to retrieve it whenever needed, no matter if it was changed by the thread in the meanwhile or not.

Would changing my `Runnable` to a `Callable` help? If yes, how?

Comment: Unable to reproduce using `jdk1.8.0_91`. It runs, and prints a boolean value every 10 seconds.

Comment: @Andreas I am currently using `1.7.0_79` and am not able to update. Could this be the cause?

Comment: your Request.run() method just spins with no pause.

Comment: @efekctive Because I need the thread to keep running unless the whole program exits

Comment: This is just a side-note, but your `if (!request.getOk()) request.setOk(true);` should really be an `AtomicBoolean` [`compareAndSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html#compareAndSet-boolean-boolean-) operation. I don't think it will cause a problem with the way your code is written exactly here in your post, because the logic is relatively simple, but it's possible for threads to interleave in between a get and set like that.

Comment: That is clear but it needs an sleep to let others access the synchronized methods. That thread is impossible to kill if it needs to be killed

Comment: To add to my previous comment, I guess you could also make another synchronized method since you're already using synchronization. The point is that the get and set should be in the same synchronized block or it should be atomic.

Comment: @Radiodef Okay, makes sense. What do you mean by putting the get and set in the "same" synchronized block?

Comment: Like `public synchronized void attemptReset() { if (!this.getOk()) this.setOk(true); }`. The reason is that hypothetically a thread could, for example, call `setOk` after the main thread checks `getOk` but before the main thread calls `setOk`. Like I said, it might be fine the way it is for the simple logic in your example here, but it's the kind of thing that can cause a problem if your threads were doing more complicated stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by saying 'I can't get the value of request.getOk() in the main thread'?

Answer (score 0):

Your example still leaves some holes in the thread-safety. Like mentioned by @Radiodef using `AtomicBoolean` can relieve you of most of the synchronisation if used properly.

Using your example, this is a thread safe Request class that accepts a message, like an answer to a http request.

```
public final class Request implements Runnable {
    private final AtomicBoolean ok = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    // volatile variables promote reference changes through all threads
    private volatile String msg;

    private boolean setMessage(String responseMessage) {
        if (this.ok.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            this.msg = msg;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean hasMessage() {
        // *pure* getters don't need synchronisation!
        return this.ok.get();
    }

    public String getMessageAndReset() {
        // make a copy before resetting the OK
        String msgCopy = this.msg;
        this.ok.compareAndSet(true, false);
        return msgCopy;
    }

    public void run() {
        final Random rand = new Random();
        try {
            while(true) {
                // sleep at random max 5 seconds
                // (simulate unpredictable network)
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(rand.nextInt(5));
                while(!setMessage("Incoming message")) {
                    // busy waiting ... waits until the current value has   
                    // been retrieved by the main thread
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And your main class:

```
public final class MainClazz implements Runnable {
    private final ExecutorService exec;
    private final Request request;

    public void MainClazz() {
        this.exec = new Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        this.request = new Request();

        this.exec.execute(request);
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (request.hasMessage()) {
                System.out.println(request.getMessageAndReset());
            }
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClazz main = new MainClazz();
        main.run();
    }
}
```

In this implementation, the `Request` class only holds a single value at a time. Depending the amount of data you expect you might want to think about using a buffer.

Also, like many others have mentioned, don't use `while (true)`! Get a synchronisation object from the java [concurrent package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)!

More light reading on the [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) object.